# Kivy: Set label text then change it after a second

Tags: python, kivy

I have made a coin flip button that shows the result in Label, every time the button is pressed, the result change according to the function.

```
def coin_flip(self):
    sound_1 = SoundLoader.load('coin.wav')
    res = random.randint(1,2)
    if sound_1:
        sound_1.play()
    if res == 1:
        self.coin_f_result.text = "HEAD"
    else:
        self.coin_f_result.text = "TAIL"
```

What I want to do is, showing the result in the Label, and then, after a second set the Label text as " ". Here's what I tried, but i only get the function calling delayed, and the label text is set directly to " ".

```
def coin_flip(self):
    sound_1 = SoundLoader.load('dice.wav')
    res = random.randint(1,2)
    if sound_1:
        sound_1.play()
    if res == 1:
        self.coin_f_result.text = "HEAD"
        time.sleep(1)
        self.coin_f_result.text = " "
    else:
        self.coin_f_result.text = "TAIL"
        time.sleep(1)
        self.coin_f_result.text = " "
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never use `time.sleep()` in an event driven framework such as kivy. It just blocks execution and as you saw, events are not handled. Use [`Clock.schedule_once()`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.clock.html) instead. For example, in the same class that has the `coin_flip` method, define

```
def reset_label(self, *args):
    self.coin_f_result.text = ' '
```

And at the end of `coin_flip()` write

```
Clock.schedule_once(self.reset_label, 1)
```

For smooth transitions you can pair that with [`Animation`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.animation.html), too.